# in vscode, even after installing the salesforce extension pack, it says sfdx components not found. what do i do

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce-developer, salesforce-sfdx

i have tasks to do in vs code using sfdx commands.so i installed the salesforce extensions. but it shows no match found if i search for sfdx. even if i restart the vs code and reinstall the extensions, it still says no match found. what do i do

i want the sfdx commands to be accessable asap